# What does it mean to say "if (binding.hasErrors())" in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In this example, I don't understand what the `BindingResult` is for and what it means to say `if (binding.hasErrors())` below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String submit(@ModelAttribute(TEST) @Valid final Test test, final BindingResult binding,
    final HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap modelMap)
{

    if (binding.hasErrors())
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BindingResult` is a data binding result associated with the previous argument (that is, `test`). It holds information about the errors of binding request parameters to the properties of `test`, such as type mismatches. When `@Valid` annotation is present, it also holds errors produced by the authomatic validation of `test`.

So, `binding.hasErrors()` determines whether errors was found during binding and validation of the `test`. When such errors present, the typical behaviour is to redisplay the form with errors messages.